# How should I behave well when I meet with my director?

Tags: professionalism, management, communication, project-management, meetings

Well, I'm doing a job in a private institute. The director is very nice person and supportive. I have to give status reports of my job, he has given me one job and it's going to one entire year and it's going to end (That was a big project).

When director had given me force to complete the job early, every time, I was making promise to complete early (I was a fresher).

> Just, I'm clueless, how should I behave with my director in professional way?
>   Can you explain please, when I meet with director with respect to status report, what should my body language and Verbal Language?

Comment: Body Language: **Like a normal person**; As far as you don't use swear words and/or appear haughty, you are good.

Comment: respectful and confident

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, be respectful.  He/She is a director after all. Also try to think ahead about what questions they're going to ask about your project and think how you can respond to them in a good and positive way.

As the comments say, be yourself, and try not to be nervous.  They are people after all, and it'll take time to build a relationship with them.

The one thing I would also advise is read The Clean Coder, it has a section on the Language of Committment.  The reason I bring this up, is that you've been forced to finish the project early (if I've understood correctly), and so you've got to deliver.  If they push for an update, don't say "I'll try", because that will imply that you've not been trying up to this point.  I see this in a lot of new developers who are eager to please. (I know for a fact that I did it, and sometimes I still fall in to this trap!!)

But otherwise, be respectful, and if you have to defend your corner, do it but with the language of respect. They should be willing to listen to you, as you have a better idea of where your work is at than they do, and you know how much you may/may not have left to get done.

Hope that helps

Comment: Please don't post "thanks" as a comment - comments are there to improve the answer, not to act as a discussion forum.